# Blanket statement vs sweeping statement

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage

Wiktionary currently defines a [blanket statement](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blanket_statement) as follows:

> 1. A type of fallacy from making an inductive conclusion with insufficient evidence; a kind of faulty generalization; underpowered generalization
> 2. A sentence wherein one wrongly assumes that one truth applies to a vast set of possibilities

In contrast, the entry for [sweeping](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sweeping) includes this:

> 1. wide, broad, affecting or touching upon many things
>
>    *The government will bring in sweeping changes to the income tax system.*
>
>    *He loves making sweeping statements without the slightest evidence.*

Therefore, I believe that blanket statements are a subset of sweeping statements: any blanket statement is necessarily a sweeping statement, because faultily generalizing to too many cases must involve "touching upon many things." But perhaps I am assuming that every blanket statement under definition (1.) necessarily satisfies definition (2.). Regardless, Wiktionary is not the one and only source for definitions.

What are some similarities and differences between blanket statements and sweeping statements?

---

Related:
[Meaning of expression " blanket rationale "](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48066/meaning-of-expression-blanket-rationale),
[What does "sweeping phrases" mean? And How should the sentence be understood?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263213/what-does-sweeping-phrases-mean-and-how-should-the-sentence-be-understood),
[Word that describes a sentence which deals in absolutes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310658/word-that-describes-a-sentence-which-deals-in-absolutes).

Comment: It's innovative to notice that blanket statements are a subset of sweeping statements. Then there's no defining similarites and differences.

Comment: Neither definition in Wikipedia is good. Go to more nuanced dictionaries; reject this effort to be precise about the relationship between these two words.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on the fallacy that Wikipaedia is reliable.

Comment: @Chenmunka that's fine, although I think the question would still be interesting and valuable if it used definitions from OED or another source. "What are some similarities and differences between blanket statements and sweeping statements?"

Answer (score 1):

OED

> **Sweeping**: figurative. **Having a wide scope; extensive, comprehensive, all-inclusive; wholesale, indiscriminate.**

> **Blanket**: Originally U.S. **Covering or including all or many cases, contingencies, situations, etc.; inclusive; all-embracing.**

You will note

(i) the lack of reference in both to the quality of any supporting evidence.

(ii) the nuances of both.

> any blanket statement is necessarily a sweeping statement

How would you show that any sweeping statement is not a blanket statement?